# Interpreting events that comprise of "smaller" events.

Tags: probability

I want to ask a question about probability on graph. Let 1,2,3,4 be vertices of a graph G. Each edge (e.g. 12,24) has the probability of appearing p. Let A be the event that the triangle 123 appears in the graph, and B the event the triangle 234 appears in the graph.

My intuition tells me that I should interpret the event $A \cap B$ as "either A or B occurs", i.e. "either 123 or 234 appears in the graph, or both". But see things this way make it hard to compute the probability. On the other hand, if I just focus on the edges, then $A \cap B$ would just be the event "edge 23 appears". But this isn't compatible with the first interpretation that I have.

Which would be the correct way to analyze this problem and where has my analysis gone wrong? The formulae for $P(A \cup B)$ and $P(A \cap B)$ would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A \cap B)$ is the probability of *both* occurring simultaneously, not either; $P(A \textrm{ or } B) = 1 - P(\not A \cap\not B) = P(A \cup B).$

The probability of $A$ occurring is $p^3$, assuming the chances for edges appearing are independent. Can you extrapolate from there?